# Calculate difference between groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Hi how could I calculate conditionally create a column that is based on diffrence with the next group? The dataframe is sorted

```
country  fruit   time   group   group_start_time
UK       apple   12:20   a      12:20
UK       apple   12:22   a      12:20
UK       banana  12:22   b      12:22 
UK       apple   12:26   c      12:26
```

The goal is that if the difference between the the current and the next group is under 5 minutes, they can be part of the same group. (Group B's start time is within 5 minutes of Group A.  Group C's start time is within 5 minutes of Group B.)

Expected Output

```
country  fruit   time   group  group_start_time   new_group
UK       apple   12:20   a      12:20                 a
UK       apple   12:22   a      12:20                 a
UK       banana  12:22   b      12:22                 a
UK       apple   12:26   c      12:26                 a
```

Comment: do the groups need to be consecutive or not? For instance if `b` had a time of 13:00 would `c` still cluster with `a`?

Comment: What is the type of your "time" column?

Comment: It is based on the start time for the group, so if 1pm that would not affect the calculation. Time is a datetime column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first sort the groups by start time, you can mask the groups within 5 min of each other and apply a `ffill`:

```
m = pd.to_timedelta(df['group_start_time']+':00').diff().le('5min')
df['new_group'] = df['group'].mask(m).ffill()
```

output:

```
  country   fruit   time group group_start_time new_group
0      UK   apple  12:20     a            12:20         a
1      UK   apple  12:22     a            12:20         a
2      UK  banana  12:22     b            12:22         a
3      UK   apple  12:26     c            12:26         a
```

Comment: Thank you. But would this generalise? If I wanted to condition if the difference in values is 5 (instead of time), could that work?

Comment: You can use whatever condition you want. Please provide and example if you're stuck.